# Why maven? What are the benefits?

Tags: java, maven, build, build-process

What are the main benefits of using maven compared to let's say ant ?
It seems to be more of a annoyance than a helpful tool.
I use maven 2, with plain Eclipse Java EE (no m2eclipse), and tomcat.

Supporters of maven believe that

1. Maven lets you get your package dependencies easily
2. Maven forces you to have a standard directory structure

In my experience

1. Figuring out package dependencies is really not that hard. You rarely do it anyway. Probably once during project setup and few more during upgrades. With maven you'll end up fixing mismatched dependencies, badly written poms, and doing package exclusions anyway.
2. Slow FIX-COMPILE-DEPLOY-DEBUG cycle, which kills productivity. This is my main gripe. You make a change, the you have to wait for maven build to kick in and wait for it to deploy. No hot deployment whatsoever.

Or am I just doing it wrong ? Please point me to the right direction, I'm all ears.

Comment: I'm really interested with point 2. Does anyone else notice the slow fix-compile-deploy cycle ? or everyone kinda knows but keeps quiet about it since maven is the best we've got/most common/coolest thing. Creating a war/ear to deploy is bad enough, maven is making it worse. 
It takes rougly 5 secs on my machine to view a jsp change on a maven project, on a exploded directory structure ? less than 1 sec. I can save multiple times, and it only compiles the latest change, on maven ? every save triggers a build.

Comment: Maybe maven it's not the problem here, but IDE support/plugin ? However, maven been around for quite some time, if we can't get it right, should we move/invent/propose something else ? besides Ivy

Comment: @Javid While the title of the question looks similar, the body of the question is different IMO and I don't consider it as a dupe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335351/what-does-maven-do-in-theory-and-in-practice-when-is-it-worth-to-use-it

Comment: For a second it sounded like you were talking about NuGet ...

Answer (score 111):

> Figuring out package dependencies is really not that hard. You rarely do it anyway. Probably once during project setup and few more during upgrades. With maven you'll end up fixing mismatched dependencies, badly written poms, and doing package exclusions anyway.

Not that hard... for toy projects. But the projects I work on have many, really many, of them, and I'm very glad to get them transitively, to have a standardized naming scheme for them. Managing all this manually by hand would be a nightmare.

And yes, sometimes you have to work on the convergence of dependencies. But think about it twice, this is not inherent to Maven, this is inherent to any system using dependencies (and I am talking about Java dependencies in general here).

So with Ant, you have to do the **same** work except that you have to do everything manually: grabbing some version of project A and its dependencies, grabbing some version of project B and its dependencies, figuring out yourself what exact versions they use, checking that they don't overlap, checking that they are not incompatible, etc. Welcome to hell.

On the other hand, Maven supports dependency management and will retrieve them transitively for me and gives me the tooling I need to manage the complexity **inherent to dependency management**: I can analyze a dependency tree, control the versions used in transitive dependencies, exclude some of them **if** required, control the converge across modules, etc. There is no magic. But at least you have support.

And don't forget that dependency management is only a small part of what Maven offers, there is much more (not even mentioning the other tools that integrates nicely with Maven, e.g. [Sonar](http://sonar.codehaus.org/)).

> Slow FIX-COMPILE-DEPLOY-DEBUG cycle, which kills productivity. This is my main gripe. You make a change, the you have to wait for maven build to kick in and wait for it to deploy. No hot deployment whatsoever.

First, why do you use Maven like this? I don't. I use my IDE to write tests, code until they pass, refactor, deploy, hot deploy and run a local Maven build when I'm done, before to commit, to make sure I will not break the continuous build.

Second, I'm not sure using Ant would make things much better. And to my experience, modular Maven builds using binary dependencies gives me faster build time than typical monolithic Ant builds. Anyway, have a look at [Maven Shell](http://shell.sonatype.org/) for a ready to (re)use Maven environment (which is awesome by the way).

So at end, and I'm sorry to say so, it's not really Maven that is killing your productivity, it's you misusing your tools. And if you're not happy with it, well, what can I say, don't use it. Personally, I'm using Maven since 2003 and I never looked back.

Comment: @Pascal, can you tell what tools you are using ? IDE, plugins, etc. Are you telling us that if I change a .properties file, or a jsp file, this will be hot deployed _without_ doing a maven build ? (maybe hot deploy is not the correct term here). I wasn't clear with what I meant with ant. I meant using the standard exploded directory during development and use ant to create a war/ear before release. For an exploded directory the rules are simple, copy/compile files from src to classes and don't touch the rest.

Comment: continued ... However, in my projects, what's being deployed onto tomcat is the jars of the modules. If I change a .jsp, doesn't maven have to rebuild those jars ?

Comment: You have to admit, most projects are toy projects, aka simple dependencies. That's just law of statistics.

Comment: @trix, if your project is small project may be then Maven is overkill for you, you don't have to use maven then. 
Every tool will address specific problems. If you don't have that problems which are solved by Maven then you don't have to use it right?

Comment: @trix, about hot deployment ant vs. maven: if you are not doing ant build for hot deployment, why are you using Maven for the same?
I guess if you use ant for the same, it would take atleast the same amount of time...isn't it?

Comment: @trix I'm using mostly Eclipse and the WTP to deploy my apps during development. My setup is similar to the one described in [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405653/can-a-multi-module-m2eclipse-wtp-project-get-utility-modules-deployed-into-web-in). Whether you use the maven-eclipse-project or m2eclipse doesn't matter, the key is to use the WTP during development. And if you still insist on not using the WTP, Maven and the war plugin also support exploded directory.

Comment: @trix And no, I don't think that most projects actually have simple dependencies. Use say Wicket, Spring, Hibernate, Guava, logback and you already have a very decent bunch of them, with regular changes. And these projects are certainly not the exception but more the rule statistically speaking.

Comment: So Pascal, could you please say to us how do you have a project configured to Maven nature and do not use the build process to deploy ? This is the point 2 of the initial question. I'm wondering how to do that , so really appreciate if you are able to give us a clear explanation.

Comment: But to be honest it´s not really easy to fully understand maven and it´s concepts. I´m using it now for at least 2 or 3 years for almost every project and am still learning. And I would say it lacks some "special" functionality - but where you can *integrate* ANT.
When I saw the first time the result of a "eclipse:eclipse" in a complicated project, I was convinced.

Comment: IDE support for maven projects have improved immensely. Maven is actually the only way to portably use Netbeans, IntelliJ and eclipse on the same non-trivial project.

Comment: +1, that's another golden medal which makes 100 golden medals!! Congratulations :D! Sorry couldn't resist!

Answer (score 20):

Maven can be considered as complete project development tool not just build tool like Ant.
You should use [Eclipse IDE with maven plugin](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html) to fix all your problems.

Here are few advantages of Maven, quoted from the [Benefits of using Maven](http://maven.apache.org/benefits-of-using-maven.html) page:

> #### Henning
>
> - quick project setup, no complicated build.xml files, just a POM and go
> - all developers in a project use the same jar dependencies due to
>     centralized POM.
> - getting a number of reports and metrics for a project "for free"
> - reduce the size of source distributions, because jars can be
>     pulled from a central location
>
> #### Emmanuel Venisse
>
> - a lot of goals are available so it isn't necessary to develop some
>     specific build process part contrary
>     to ANT we can reuse existing ANT tasks
>     in build process with antrun plugin
>
> #### Jesse Mcconnell
>
> - Promotes modular design of code. by making it simple to manage mulitple
>     projects it allows the design to be
>     laid out into muliple logical parts,
>     weaving these parts together through
>     the use of dependency tracking in pom
>     files.
> - Enforces modular design of code. it is easy to pay lipservice to modular
>     code, but when the code is in seperate
>     compiling projects it is impossible to
>     cross pollinate references between
>     modules of code unless you
>     specifically allow for it in your
>     dependency management... there is no
>     'I'll just do this now and fix it
>     later' implementations.
> - Dependency Management is clearly declared. with the dependency
>     management mechanism you have to try
>     to screw up your jar
>     versioning...there is none of the
>     classic problem of 'which version of
>     this vendor jar is this?' And setting
>     it up on an existing project rips the
>     top off of the existing mess if it
>     exists when you are forced to make
>     'unknown' versions in your repository
>     to get things up and running...that or
>     lie to yourself that you know the
>     actual version of ABC.jar.
> - strong typed life cycle there is a strong defined lifecycle that a
>     software system goes thru from the
>     initiation of a build to the end...
>     and the users are allowed to mix and
>     match their system to the lifecycle
>     instead of cobble together their own
>     lifecycle.. this has the additional
>     benefit of allowing people to move
>     from one project to another and speak
>     using the same vocabulary in terms of
>     software building
>
> #### Vincent Massol
>
> - Greater momentum: Ant is now legacy and not moving fast ahead. Maven is
>     forging ahead fast and there's a
>     potential of having lots of high-value
>     tools around Maven (CI, Dashboard
>     project, IDE integration, etc).

Comment: While down voting please provide reason, that is non said but ethical rule on stackoverflow.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with references but you really need to make it clear that the content is not yours.

Comment: Thanks. I will make sure that I quote it other than just mentioning where it was referenced from. just 30 odd days old at stackoverflow and still learning the art :).

Answer (score 11):

Figuring out dependencies for small projects is not hard.  But once you start dealing with a dependency tree with hundreds of dependencies, things can easily get out of hand.  (I'm speaking from experience here ...)

The other point is that if you use an IDE with incremental compilation and Maven support (like Eclipse + m2eclipse), then you should be able to set up edit/compile/hot deploy and test.

I personally don't do this because I've come to distrust this mode of development due to bad experiences in the past (pre Maven).  Perhaps someone can comment on whether this actually works with Eclipse + m2eclipse.

Comment: One could start with maven to get all the dependencies then copy the dependencies to his project, right ?

Comment: I suppose you could.  But that would be liable to break if you updated your project's dependencies ... or if your project depended on snapshots.

Comment: I mean have 2 projects, the maven project's sole purpose is to get dependencies. Use version control to keep track the changes between dependency updates. I do this anyway, just so I can see the changes, in case it breaks my build.

Comment: Ughh.  That's not how Maven is designed to be used.  One of the big benefits of Maven is avoiding checking dependent libraries into version control.  With your approach, you'll clutter up your VCS with lots of versions of lots of binary files.  And some VCSs are particularly bad at handling binary files.

Comment: Yes I know, but I got burned so many times when after an upgrade, the build breaks. Version control lets me pinpoint the likely cause quickly.

Comment: @trix - assuming you weren't depending on snapshots, you could just rollback the Maven dependencies.  Snapshot dependencies ... well yes, that's the risk of snapshot dependencies.  For them, I'm inclined to checkout the source code and build on my dev box so that I'm in control of when any updates propagate to my builds.

Comment: I only use snapshot dependencies to refer to things under the control of myself (or at least my team; if they break something, I can go and shout at them or otherwise “persuade” them to be more careful). External dependencies are always done as release points, and if they're changing, You're Doing It Wrong.

Comment: Generally you learn the hard way to be very weary of any kind of magic when writing programs :-S

Comment: Version control also lets you rollback the change in your pom.xml that included the new dependency very easily

Answer (score 9):

Maven is one of the tools where you need to actually *decide* up front that you like it and want to use it, since you will spend quite some time learning it, and having made said decision once and for all will allow you to skip all kinds of doubt while learning (because you *like* it and *want* to use it)!

The strong conventions help in many places - like Hudson that can do wonders with Maven projects - but it may be hard to see initially.

edit: As of 2016 Maven is the only Java build tool where all three major IDEs can use the sources out of the box.  In other words, using maven makes your build IDE-agnostic.  This allows for e.g. using Netbeans profiling even if you normally work In eclipse

Comment: And the opposite is also true, a lot of people come to maven with preconceived hatred, because it's not ant, etc.

Comment: The opposite?  You mean?

Answer (score 9):

Maven advantages over ant are quite a few. I try to summarize them here.

**Convention over Configuration**
Maven uses a distinctive approach for the project layout and startup, that makes easy to just jump in a project. Usually it only takes the checkount and the maven command to get the artifacts of the project.

**Project Modularization**
Project conventions suggest (or better, force) the developer to modularize the project. Instead of a monolithic project you are often forced to divide your project in smaller sub components, which make it easier debug and manage the overall project structure

**Dependency Management and Project Lifecycle**
Overall, with a good SCM configuration and an internal repository, the dependency management is quite easy, and you are again forced to think in terms of Project Lifecycle - component versions, release management and so on. A little more complex than the ant something, but again, an improvement in quality of the project.

**What is wrong with maven?** 
Maven is not easy. The build cycle (what gets done and when) is not so clear within the POM. Also, some issue arise with the quality of components and missing dependencies in public repositories.
The best approach (to me) is to have an internal repository for caching (and keeping) dependencies around, and to apply to release management of components. For projects bigger than the sample projects in a book, you will thank maven before or after

Answer (score 6):

Maven can provide benefits for your build process by employing standard conventions and practices to accelerate your development cycle while at the same time helping you achieve a higher rate of success. For a more detailed look at how Maven can help you with your development process please refer to The Benefits of Using Maven.

Answer (score 3):

Maven is a powerful project management tool that is based on POM (project object model). It is used for projects build, dependency and documentation.
It simplifies the build process like ANT. But it is too much advanced than ANT.
Maven helps to manage-
Builds,Documentation,Reporing,SCMs,Releases,Distribution.
- maven repository is a directory of packaged JAR file with pom.xml file. Maven searches for  dependencies in the repositories.

Answer (score 2):

I've never come across point 2? Can you explain why you think this affects deployment in any way. If anything maven allows you to structure your projects in a modularised way that actually allows hot fixes for bugs in a particular tier, and allows independent development of an API from the remainder of the project for example.

It is possible that you are trying to cram everything into a single module, in which case the problem isn't really maven at all, but the way you are using it.

Comment: I'm using plain eclipse jee, maven 2 and tomcat. Obviously a web app. If I'm changing a properties file, or a jsp, in order to see my changes on tomcat, maven has to do its build, create a war/ear and deploy to tomcat. This is slow compared to if I use an exploded directory structure.

Comment: @trix Hot deploy under Eclipse with Tomcat just works. You're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This should have been a comment, but it wasn't fitting in a comment length, so I posted it as an answer.

All the benefits mentioned in other answers are achievable by simpler means than using maven. If, for-example, you are new to a project, you'll anyway spend more time creating project architecture, joining components, coding than downloading jars and copying them to lib folder. If you are experienced in your domain, then you already know how to start off the project with what libraries. I don't see any benefit of using maven, especially when it poses a lot of problems while automatically doing the "dependency management".

I only have intermediate level knowledge of maven, but I tell you, I have done large projects(like ERPs) without using maven.