# Fail to run the demo of this java application

Tags: java, maven

I am completely new to Java, just learned a little because I need to run this project: https://github.com/ansjsun/ansj_seg

I have run

```
mvn compile
```

and some other stuff.

Now, in ansj_seg/target I have a file named ansj_seg-0.8.jar, which seems important, although I don't know how to use it.

In ansj_seg/src/test/java/org/ansj/demo, there are some demos, and I want to run BaseAnalysisDemo.java, I tried as following.

Step one, I compile using:

```
javac -classpath ~/Downloads/ansj_seg/target/ansj_seg-0.8.jar  BaseAnalysisDemo.java
```

It works fine and generates BaseAnalysisDemo.class.

But when I try to run it using

```
java BaseAnalysisDemo
```

An error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: BaseAnalysisDemo (wrong name: org/ansj/demo/BaseAnalysisDemo)
```

I guess I should set some path, but have no idea.

Anyone can help?

BTW, I prefer using command line to Eclipse.

The directory structure is like this(Updated):

```
\ansj_seg
    pom.xml
    \src
        \main
            \java
                \org
                    \ansj
                        \app
                        \dic
                        \domain
                        ...
            \resource
                ...
        \test
            \java
                \org
                    \ansj
                        \demo
                            BaseAnalysisDemo.java
                            Demo.java
                            ...
                        \test
                            ...
```

Here is another question, even if the demo can be run, how can I use this java library in another place? I guess the file ansj_set-0.8.jar should be used. Again, I know nothing about Java.. Any suggestion will be very helpful.

---

Updated:

If I run with classpath specified:

```
java -classpath ~/Downloads/ansj_seg/target/ansj_seg-0.8.jar BaseAnalysisDemo
```

still got an error, but different:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: BaseAnalysisDemo
```

Comment: You will need to get someone who can read Chinese to help you.  The documentation is all in Chinese.

Comment: **I am completely new to Java** : then avoid maven . **just first learn java the normal way **.
 [a question about maven benefits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589562/why-maven-what-are-the-benefits)

Comment: This may not solve your current problem but you should use classpath you used while compiling also while running your application.

Comment: @Pshemo, I updated my post. I tried to specified the classpath when running, but still fail...

Comment: @StephenC, I think to run the project requires no knowledge of Chinese..all source code and demo code are there..just compile and link problem...

Answer (score 0):

You will fall back to Eclipse soon, because what you'd like to do is a bit cumbersome, but doable.

Try this:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="java.org.ansj.demo.BaseAnalysisDemo.java"
```

If you need arguments too, add `-Dexec.args` to the list.

Note that you'll have to move your demo under the main source tree.

Comment: I still cannot get it work..and I decide to learn Eclipse..anyway..thank you very much!

Comment: What is the exact error you get? Have you tried to run this where you have your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: I updated my original post. Please refer to the directory structure. I am in the directory \ansj_seg, and running the code you give me. An error occurs:"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.org.ansj.demo.BaseAnalysisDemo.java". Plus, I tried to use Dexec.mainClass="src.test.java.org.ansj.demo.BaseAnalysisDemo.java" and Dexec.mainClass="test.java.org.ansj.demo.BaseAnalysisDemo.java", still not work...

Comment: Do not put `src`/`test` to the classname, because it is not in your package declaration. You can only refer to classes under the `src` dir this way, test sources are available only under testing. Your package declarations are correct, I checked at Github. Put the demo class under `src`, as I suggested.