# How to make Maven overlays working in Eclipse/Tomcat "Serve modules without publishing" mode?

Tags: tomcat, m2eclipse, war, eclipse-wtp

We are developing JavaEE application using *Eclipse* (3.7/Indigo), *Tomcat* (6/7) and *m2e-wtp* (0.13.1). The application is using Maven overlay to reuse resources provided by another application.

Current situation, which is pretty annoying, is that each code change triggers a republish, and usually requires server restart. As advised [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405653/can-a-multi-module-m2eclipse-wtp-project-get-utility-modules-deployed-into-web-in/3408222#3408222), I would like to enable *Serve modules without publishing* checkbox to use hot code replacement instead of publishing.

However, when running in this mode, resources from the overlayed application are not available. This seems to be caused by **lack of proper overlay support in m2e-wtp**. There is [an issue](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MECLIPSEWTP-164) recently raised in m2e-wtp bugtracker, but it is unlikely to be fixed in a near future.

**What is the best workaround to use overlays in *Serve modules without publishing* mode?**

Answer (score 5):

WTP doesn't know anything about the concept of overlays, so fixing it will be tricky. War Overlay support in WTP is already a huge hack. 
For now, I opened https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MECLIPSEWTP-172 which might help you a bit. Basically changes in overlays won't be automatically published.

Comment: Not fully answers my question on the workaround, but I'm very glad to see m2e-wtp project lead here and trying to help. Upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Should be fixed afaik :

[Fred Bricon added a comment - 09/14/11 11:32 AM](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MECLIPSEWTP-172?focusedCommentId=138714&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-138714)

Fixed with commit 45b50868204f. Server module cache eviction was removed with MECLIPSE-176. So the new preference option (Window > Preferences > Server > Overlays) just prevents server incremental publish when an overlay dependency is modified.

However, it doesn't change the fact that WTP redeploys the master webapp when a class is modified.