# Force unpacking with maven-dependency-plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e, eclipse-kepler

Im am using *Maven 3.2.1* with *Eclipse Kepler*. I have a dynamic web project which has a dependency to another component which includes some JSPs. I now want the JSPs from the dependency to become part of the web root of the dynamic web project. I chose to accomplish this by using *unpack* goal of the *maven-dependency-plugin*.

I added a plugin definition to unpack the JARs into `/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources`. Unfortunatley Eclipse from time to time cleans this folder and teh JSPs are gone. In order to unpack them again I have to delete the `target/dependency-maven-plugin-markers`folder. Otherwise the plugin will not unpack the files again.

Is it possible to force the unpacking and ignore the plugin markers?

Is there a better way to get web resources from a dependency into my Dynamic Web Project?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there's a better way, but it's not compatible with Tomcat's "serve  module without publishing" feature (or Weblogic's equivalent thing)

Remove your maven-dependency-plugin configuration and add your dependency as a war overlay instead. If your dependency is a war, it'll be automatically recognized as an overlay (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html). If it's a zip or a jar, you need to add a specific configuration to your maven-war-plugin definition. Something along :

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <overlays>
      <overlay>
        <!-- /!\ must also be added as a project dependency-->
        <groupId>foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>bar</artifactId> 
        <type>jar</type>
        <targetPath>relative/path/to/contextroot</targetPath>
       </overlay>
     </overlays>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Before deployment, resources will be unzipped under target/m2e-wtp/overlays/bar-version.jar/ and then deployed onto your application server

Comment: Hm. Does not really work. Even without having the overlay configured Eclipse puts dependencies to WARs into `target/m2e-wtp/overlays`. But these files (JSPs in my case) are not found when I start the web project in Weblogic server.

Comment: Maybe try to deploy as exploded archives. Weblogic doesn't seem to handle multiple web resource folders very well when serving the webapp in situ. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124864/m2e-wtp-overlay-not-loading-into-eclipse-published-ear-or-war-files/21169684#21169684

Comment: But then I would loose the Hot-Swap and Debugging functionality,wouldn't I?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea, I don't use WebLogic